# How to create recurring payments in Stripe.Net

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm new to Stripet.Net.
I would like to write code for recurring payments.
These payments they vary, some customers will pay every month some will pay every 3rd month, different amounts, different currencies.

I would like to dynamically set the amount via the API not add price ID on Dashboard.

How can I achieve this?
I was told that I have to add the product and the price to the subscription, which is very confusing.

Please see my code below :

```
StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = _Configs.StripeApiKey;

var options = new SubscriptionItemCreateOptions
{
    Subscription = "sub_1JeZZY2eZvKYlo342C1mrFyp4h",
    Price = "price_1L9EC82eZvKYlo2CiupNi342tGO",
    Quantity = 1,
        
};

var service = new SubscriptionItemService();
service.Create(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

First I'd recommend carefully reading Stripe's thorough documentation on using Products and Prices in their API to model your business model after:

- [How Products and Prices work](https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/how-products-and-prices-work)
- [Getting started](https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/getting-started)

Overall, their API expects you to first create a Product to represent what you sell and a Price to represent the currency and amount and optionally the frequency of the payments (every week or month or year). It's common to have a monthly Price and a yearly Price for example both tied to the same Product.

Having that hierarchy allows you to better organize your offering across various features that Stripe offers from analytics on your revenue to upselling the yearly Price when someone looks to pay for the monthly and others.

You mentioned that you have dynamic pricing for customers. An example of such a business model is an insurance company that adapts their pricing to a lot of criteria where each end customer pays a different amount. In that world, you'd create a Product for your service/what you sell first. Then you'd create a separate Price object with the right currency/amount/frequency. This can easily be done in the API using the Create Price [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create) and passing the right `amount`, `currency` and other parameters. You would tie each Price to the same Product by passing `product=prod_12345` as the id of the Product you create before.

Once you have a Price, you can create a Subscription to that Price which the code in your question already does. Stripe covers this in details in their [Billing quickstart](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart) which is an end to end example in all languages they support.

Finally, if you don't want to have to first create a Price and then a Subscription, you can use the `price_data` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-items-price_data) to create the Price inline as you create the Subscription. You will still need to have created a Product upfront though.